# What permissions are needed for apache Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Running Ubuntu 10.04 on Linode, RVM, Rails 3, Apache with Passenger module, carrierwave and mini-magick

I get:

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
```

and `Errno::EACCES (Permission denied /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/public/uploads/tmp/20110517-1707-2938-6455):`

I ran `chmod -R root:root /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp`

Then: `chmod -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp` & `chmod -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/public/uploads`

Since the only 2 directories that should be writable is the log files and uploads directory I tried to secure the rest.  Are there any other folders / files that I need to make writable?

Comment: I think, you should use chown instead of chmod to set owner and group. And use chmod to set actual permission mode. To inspect permissions and ownership use command ls -l /path/to/file_or_directory

Comment: @taro - you where right.  its been a while since i've worked with linux.  did `chown -R root:root /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp` then did `chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/log /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/public/uploads` and `chmod 772 /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/log /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/public/uploads`.  Does this sound right?

Comment: Looks right, but probably there is no such group root, there is wheel.  Also, it is common to set chmod 755 for directories in such cases.

Comment: did that work for you after all?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Permissions on web sites is a little strange: on the one hand, the content needs to be readable by the webserver and `FastCGI` or `Passenger` or whatever executes the (in this case, Ruby) code. On the other hand, if the webserver user *owns* the files, then a hacked webserver or (more likely :) your code could [modify the executable files and static files that are your website](https://serverfault.com/questions/267812/front-page-keeps-getting-hacked). [It happens too often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768733/fake-antivirus-redirection).

If the content of the website is owned by *some other user*, not writable by the web server software, then the website *can not be overwritten by attackers*. (Of course, you have a few open sockets to a database connection; all the database backed data can be corrupted by attackers. Also, any directory where you allow uploads could be corrupted by attackers. But the goal is to [reduce the privileges of the software as far as reasonable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).)

So, all that said, on to your specific question; your webserver software runs as `www-data`, and it makes sense for your log files and upload directory to be owned by `www-data`:

```
mkdir -p /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/log/   # might not exist yet
chown -R pcasa:pcasa /srv/www/mysite.com/   # or some other user
chmod 755 /srv/www/mysite.com
chmod 755 /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/
# populate the app directory with your files, if you haven't done so already
chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/log
chmod 755 /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/log   # see notes
chmod 644 /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/log/* # see notes
```

I made the assumption that all users on your system can read the log. This might not be true. Use `700` in place of `755` and `600` in place of `644` if you don't want all system users to read the log files.

Next, for your `uploads` directory:

```
mkdir -p /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/public/uploads/tmp  # might not exist yet
chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/public/uploads
chmod 755 /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/public/uploads
chmod 755 /srv/www/mysite.com/testapp/public/uploads/tmp
```

Again, I've made the assumption that all users on your system can be able to see all the uploaded content. Use `700` in place of `755` if you just want the webserver software to be able to read the files.

These are simple guidelines that should work; you can get more complicated if you want to keep the website software and content shared only between the user that *owns* the website and the user that *runs* the website, by running the webserver with a supplementary group (see `newgrp(1)` and `group(5)` manpages for details) and giving the files the same group owner, and using the group permission bits (the middle octal number: `750` vs `700`). It's complicated enough that unless you've got a good reason, it's probably not worth going down this route. (Definitely worth doing *once* on a development machine somewhere, just so you're familiar enough with it that you can use it in the future. :)