# Drupal 7 security implementation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, security

I have a hostgator website on which I installed Drupal. It was working fine until last weekend. I am primarily a .net developer and am not sure about the configuration of this open source application.

Recently, I noticed a large number of user accounts being created who never even logged in before. So, after setting up Google analytics, I determined that my site was hacked. I made this determination because the majority of the traffic and user flow is coming form RUSSIA, SERBIA and ROMANIA, hackers haven!

I realised that my website was not secure. So now I put the site into mainitainance mode, uninstalled the existing Drupal 7, and installed a new installation. It is very fresh now and I am on a mission to find some good security pratices.

I would like to know what security measures that I can implement other than [these](http://drupal.org/security/secure-configuration).

Also, how would I connect to my website's command line to change the file permission settings? Currently, I am using Filezilla and right clicking to change the properties.

Thanks, and apologies for the long question.

P.S.  This is my [website](http://techiequickie.com).

Comment: Written for someone else, but hopefully useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6091058/377270

Answer (score 2):

Hostgator provides [SSH access](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/getting-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access). Use tool like [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to transfer files and [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to access command line. Once you get command line access, you will be hopefully able to install [Drush on Hostgator](http://christophershumate.com/blog/how-install-drush-hostgator). [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) will help you do many administrative stuff using command line and it is highly recommended to use. Since you are a .Net developer, I assume that you might be using Windows for development. Good news is that you can install Drush on Windows too.

Are you sure that your site was really hacked? Because, if you go to Account setting page (http://your-site/admin/config/people/accounts) and look under **Who can register accounts?**, you will see three options there. The default is "Visitors can create account". If you do not change this setting to something else, your new site will again face the same problem. Otherwise, you can select option **Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account**.

Another way to reduce number of spammers creating account on your Drupal site is to install [CAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/captcha/) or [reCAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module and configure it to show challenge to users when they create an account.  This will block many spammers.  You can also [block specific IP](http://blamcast.net/articles/block-bots-hotlinking-ban-ip-htaccess) range using Apache .htaccess file. You will find .htaccess file in your Drupal installation folder.

Another good practice is to periodically update Drupal core and contributed modules for security fixes.  If you goto page **admin/reports/updates**, you will see what module requires an update. Command line and Drush will help you streamlining some part of this process.

If you regularly update Drupal (core & modules), use SSH for file transfer and apply correct file permissions, your site should be all secure. It is not that hard to maintain a secure Drupal site, given all the help is available for Drupal security team and Drupal community.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Drupal Group (forum) that deals with [Best Practices in Drupal Security](http://groups.drupal.org/best-practices-drupal-security) that provides a number of excellent suggestions on how to secure Drupal sites. As for accessing your site via the command-line, I checked and Hostgator allows for SSH access on all of their hosting plans. You should be able to login via SSH, change to the sub-directory within your Drupal installation and change the permissions of a file or directory using the 'chmod' command.

Good luck!