# Passenger 403 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am trying to install passenger for my rails app, but I dont know where is the problem.

Fallow the files:

httpd.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.53/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.53
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
   </IfModule>


<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.yourhost.com
   # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
   DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/shitatta/public 
   <Directory /home/vagrant/shitatta/public>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

error_log:

```
[Sun Feb 22 09:49:20 2015] [error] [client 192.168.33.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Sun Feb 22 09:49:20 2015] [error] [client 192.168.33.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user that execute passenger and the web server doesn't have access to

> /home/vagrant/shitatta/public

You should in my opinion make some changes:

- Login with your user (vagrant)
- Create a directory /opt/web/
- Copy your project in /opt/web/shitatta
- Go to /opt/web
- Change auth access like : `chmod 755 shitatta/*`
- Change owner : `chown -R vagrant:vagrant shitatta`
- Change your apache conf with new paths
- Add your user to www-data `adduser vagrant www-data` or any other user that will use Apache

If you have a permission denied when you run command, add sudo before each command. In my opinion it's a mistake to store your website in your home folder.

You should read about rails :

- [What permissions are needed for apache Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037286/what-permissions-are-needed-for-apache-passenger)