# Unable to access log file. Please ensure that path/to/production.log exists and is writable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, azure, passenger

I am facing the following issue to start a Rails application with Apache - Passenger in Azure platform (CentOS):

```
App 18106 stdout:
App 18106 stderr: Rails Error:
Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /path/to/production.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /path/to/production.log).
The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

App 18106 stdout:
[ 2017-06-19 11:37:13.5635 18014/7f7826db7700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/my_rails_app: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
Error ID: f684beca
Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-JB9Dio.html
Message from application: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
(PG::ConnectionBad)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:654:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:654:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:654:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
```

I have tried `chmod 0664 /path/to/production.log` but nothing changed in the error as specified above.

The same setup is working fine in AWS.

Apache `conf.d` files:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/my_app.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  ErrorLog logs/rails_app_error_log
  <Directory "/var/www/">
          Allow from all
          Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  Alias /my_rails_app /var/www/my_rails_app/public/
  <Location /my_rails_app>
          PassengerBaseURI /my_rails_app
          PassengerAppRoot /var/www/my_rails_app
  </Location>
  <Directory /var/www/my_rails_app/public/ >
          Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerUser  apache
    PassengerGroup apache
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf**:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_passenger.so
 <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/passenger-5.1.2
   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/wrappers/ruby
 </IfModule>
```

I have also set `chown -R apache:apache  my_rails_app`.

**Note:** If I run Passenger in standalone mode without using Apache, then everything works just fine.

I have searched all other relevant posts and tried to avoid the `could not connect to server: Permission denied` in the log, but nothing seems to be working.

---

## **Solution:**

I think the issue was with SElinux and issue got resolved after running the following command:

> `/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

Comment: At a guess, `logs/rails_app_error_log` is not resolving to where you think it is on the CentOS box.  Does /var/www/logs exist?

Comment: @mcfinnigan : `/var/www/my_rails_app` is the path to my rails app and it has `/var/www/my_rails_app/log/production.log`.   Also, the production.log file permissions looks like this:  `-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 14617 Jun 19 10:56 production.log`

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to the Passenger offical troubleshooting [`The Rails application reports that it's unable to start because of a permission error`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/troubleshooting/ruby/#the-rails-application-reports-that-it-s-unable-to-start-because-of-a-permission-error) for `Passenger + Apache and Ruby`, I think the issue was caused by the permissions of your Rails application's directory.

So please first check the owner of your apache process via `ps -ef|grep apache`, then to check the owner & group ownership of your Rails application's directory via `ls -l <path of rails>`, as below.

```
$ ps -ef |grep apache
root      7226     1  0 16:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7229  7226  0 16:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7230  7226  0 16:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
<user>    7756 30915  0 16:12 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache

$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 13 <user> <group> 4096 Jun 20 16:22 myrails
```

Then try to change the owner & group ownership of your Rails application's directory with `root` or `www-data` via `chown -R <OWNER>:<GROUP> myrails` with `root` or `www-data`.

And as reference, there is a similar SO thread [What permissions are needed for apache Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037286/what-permissions-are-needed-for-apache-passenger) which you can refer to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I revisited all relevant paths, changed permission to 755 and user/user groups... now application is started!!

Comment: I think it was SElinux which was blocking the request.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
chmod 777 <directory_with_logs>
```

This will give you execute/read/write privileges for whole dir. It possible that problem is with directory, not the file.

You can play with the numbers further to finely tune app.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have already tried this but did not work.